# How to force label to fit and stay in the same row via Storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uistoryboard

I've been struggling tryint to get my text label to stay in 1 row.

This is what I have now.

---

**Size Inspector**

[image]

---

**Attributes Inspector**

[image]

I kept getting:

[image]

How would one go about debugging this further?

Comment: where should I do that ? via attribute inspector menu ?

Comment: I click on the label, I see no constrain on it, https://i.imgur.com/FncT4tg.png

Comment: OK never mind, I see the problem; you're trying to use a stack view for this.

Comment: I tried to set the top and trailing as suggested, I got the right side to looks good, but it messed up the left labels. :( https://i.imgur.com/pOwxac3.png

Comment: Should I select both labels and set their constraint ? or apply the constraint on the stack level instead of individual?

Comment: Yeah, the problem is you can't use a stack view to do this. I've provided that as an answer.

Comment: ok. Thanks, I am attempt what you wrote now;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increase the width of the bedTimeFrom button.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to use a stack view in a situation for which it is not suited. Remove the stack view and place the constraints yourself: pin the From label with a leading (and top) constraint and the button with a trailing (and top) constraint.

Comment: so remove my stack view completely from the document outline ?

Comment: I'm very new to iOS, can u plz share some steps how to safely do that ?

Comment: Well, don't just delete them, as you will lose your label and button. :) But basically yes, you need to take the From Stack View and To Stack View out of the story and create the constraints yourself. You might be happiest if you replaced those stack views by (invisible) normal content views to act as superviews for the button and label.

Comment: Can I adjust existing constraint that set to my stackview right now ? This what I set to my stackview as of now. https://i.imgur.com/JqGSCu8.png

Comment: changing from 16 to 12, seems to be what I was looking for. https://i.imgur.com/5ZPqeoI.png